# Dividends on OTC market in New York

Tags: dividends

A stock trades on the Bors exchange in Oslo, which is now closed for the day.
Tomorrow is ex-div for that stock.
The same company trades OTC in New York, which is still open, and
is the same company under a different symbol
If I buy it OTC in New York today, do I get the dividend?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you will not get the dividend because trading in Oslo will not resume until the ex-div date (typically, dividends go to the owners of record before market close on the day *before* the ex-div date).

In any case, you will get one of two things - the stock at the price before the dividend and the rights to the dividend, or you'll get no dividend, but get the stock at a similar price *minus* the dividend. You won't get the stock at the lower post-dividend price AND the dividend (no free lunch).

For example, if the stock is trading at 100 and announces a dividend of 5, one option is you pay 100 for the stock today, the value of the stock will drop to 95 on the ex-div date, and you'll eventually get a dividend of 5. Or, you'll pay 95 for the stock and not get a dividend. Either way you'll end up with 95 less cash than before and a stock worth 95 (per share, of course).

(I'm intentionally ignoring "normal" market fluctuations, just focusing on the effect of the dividend)

Comment: The price will drop to 95 at the time of the ex-dividend, not when it is paid out. There are shares (eg Unilever, Shell) that trade ex-dividend for more than a month.

Comment: True - I edited to hopefully make that more clear. My main point is that you can't get the dividend _and_ pay the lower post-dividend stock price.